# Does have google closure library scrollbar?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

Does Google closure library contains something like http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar /?

I searched the library and I was found ui.ContainerScroller, etc. But all scrolling just using CSS (overflow) and not with JS. I need to scroll div in another div with styleable scrollbar. I'm very glad for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Google Closure Library does not come with a customizable scrollbar.

I see a few options:

1. Load a custom Google Closure scrollbar that someone else has created
2. Port a non-Closure variant to Google Closure
3. Import one from outside of Google Closure code via an [extern](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs)
4. Roll your own